# MySQL 8.0 query to compute recursively size at each node in the hierarchy based on the contents downstream

Tags: mysql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

This is in MySQL 8.0.

How do I use a recursive query to calculate bottom-up the size at each category node (type = 1).

```
create table hierarchy (
    name     varchar(100),
    location varchar(100),
    type     int,
    size     int,
    parent_name varchar(100),
    parent_location varchar(100)
) engine=InnoDB default charset=UTF8MB4;

truncate hierarchy;
insert into hierarchy values
    ('music', '/', 1, 0, NULL, NULL),
    ('classical', '/music', 1, 0, 'music', '/'),
    ('pop', '/music', 1, 0, 'music', '/'),
    ('bonjovi', /music/pop', 'pop', '/music'),
    ('its_my_life.mp3', '/music/pop/bonjovi', 2, 4092, 'bonjovi', '/music/pop'),
    ('bach', '/music/classical', 1, 'classical', '/music'),
    ('flute_e_min.mp3', '/music/classical/bach', 2, 1024, 'bach', '/music/classical'),
    ('sonata_no1_g.mp3, '/music/classical/bach', 2, 2048, 'bach', '/music/classical'),  
select * from hierarchy;
```

Starting with a given node in the hierarchy, in this example music, how do I achieve the size of each direct descendant category group (type = 1) by summing up recursively the sizes of files of (type = 2) up the hierarchy?

```
name         location           parent_name   parent_location   total size
'music'      '/'                NULL          NULL              7164
'classical'  '/music'           'music'       '/'               3072
'pop'        '/music'           'music'       '/'               4092
'bonjovi'    '/music/pop'       'pop'         '/music'          4092
'bach'       '/music/classical' 'classical'   '/music'          3072
...
```

Initially, the nodes of type = 1 have a default value. The query recursively computes what the size is based on the contents downstream.

For your convenience a fiddle space: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wozz4B6TEVmU95RPrQxvYd/0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this problem with a pair of recursive CTEs. The first finds all the categories based on the given node (in this case `music`), the second finds all the files associated with each of the categories and builds a table of their sizes with all their categories up to the root category. This table is then joined to the table of categories and the file sizes summed at each level:

```
WITH RECURSIVE categories AS (
  SELECT name, location, parent_name, parent_location, size
  FROM hierarchy
  WHERE name = 'music'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT h.name, h.location, h.parent_name, h.parent_location, h.size
  FROM hierarchy h
  JOIN categories c ON c.name = h.parent_name
  WHERE h.type = 1
),
filesizes AS (
  SELECT size, parent_name
  FROM hierarchy
  WHERE type = 2 AND parent_name IN (SELECT name FROM categories)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT f.size, h.parent_name
  FROM hierarchy h
  JOIN filesizes f ON f.parent_name = h.name
  WHERE h.parent_name IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT c.name, c.location, c.parent_name, c.parent_location,
       SUM(f.size) AS total_size
FROM categories c
JOIN filesizes f ON f.parent_name = c.name
GROUP BY c.name, c.location, c.parent_name, c.parent_location
```

Output:

```
name        location            parent_name     parent_location     total_size
music       /                   null            null                7164
classical   /music              music           /                   3072
pop         /music              music           /                   4092
bonjovi     /music/pop          pop             /music              4092
bach        /music/classical    classical       /music              3072
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wFSLCQyyZ7vc1HSE29JvUV/0)

Comment: @LucasTaddeus yeah - a tricky problem. I would suggest just looking at the output of each CTE individually e.g. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rhSyHBy9ZGcAnrPKRqgd3T/0 and https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d5EYnpS5dR1ByWaSUErgB3/0 to help understand how it works